# How to automate initialization of a remote Jupyter notebook on local machine?

Tags: bash, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I like to work out of a Jupyter Notebook that is connected remotely to a PC from my laptop. I'd like to automate the process of connecting to the PC by ssh, initializing a Jupyter notebook in the PC, then opening a browser on my laptop to access that notebook. At present, these are the steps I take to do this:

1. SSH into the remote PC and initialize a Jupyter notebook by the executing `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889`
2. Back on my local machine, I run `ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8889 username@PC_IP_address` to bind the remote port 8889 to the local port 8887
3. I then open a browser on my laptop to access the remote notebook at the url https://localhost:8887

Both the PC and the laptop are on the same network. I automated 2. on my local machine by creating a profile in Iterm3 that executes the script. I'd like to automate the entire process so that with one alias, I can launch a remote notebook on my local machine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a function, if I were you. Put this in your `.bashrc`

```
jupy(){
    ssh username@PC_IP_address jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
    ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8889 username@PC_IP_address
    firefox https://localhost:8887
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn’t know you can just pass arguments in ssh. I’ll try this out!

Comment: When I execute `jupyter notebook` after logging into the remote server, it works. When executing it through ssh (using `ssh username@PC_IP_address jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889`) , however, I get `bash: jupyter: command not found`. Any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: try `ssh username@PC_IP_address echo '$PATH'` and see if the command `jupyter` is in the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

After much effort, here is a hacky solution that worked for me

```
jupykaggle(){
    # arguments: projectfolder environmentname
    competitionfolder=$1
    envname=$2
    ssh USER@IPADDRESS "cd Dropbox/data_science/kaggle/${competitionfolder};
                                source /home/USER/anaconda2/bin/activate ${envname};
                                /home/USER/anaconda2/bin/conda env list;
                                kill \`lsof -t -i:8889\`;
                                /home/USER/anaconda2/envs/${envname}/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889; exit"

    # after notebook is initialized in remote host, Control+c to exit this ssh session
    # and enter the second one to bind the remote port 8889 to local port 8887
    echo "Bind remote port 8889 to local port 8887"
    ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8889 USER@IPADDRESS
}

alias jupybrowser='open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app http://localhost:8887'
```

I execute

```
jupykaggle projectfolder environmentname
```

to cd into the project directory, activate the virtual environment, kill the process running in the port I need to use, and initialize a jupyter notebook using that port (using the installation inside the virtual environment). I then exit this ssh session and enter another ssh session where I bind the remote port 8889 to the local port, 8887. The last alias just opens a Chrome browser in local host 8887 to open the notebook.

I still need to copy and paste the token from the remote notebook, but that's okay. This is still significantly fewer steps than my previous workflow.

Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a '&' after your first ssh so you don't have to control+c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).